# How to make a rectangular prism in OpenGL?

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

I am trying to make a rectangular prism, but ended up with a pyramid. What's wrong with my code?

```
float ax, ay, dx, dy, dz;

float color[3] = {0.1, 0.6, 0.1 };

float v[8][3] = { 
    -1,  1, -1, 
     1,  1, -1, 
     1, -1, -1, 
    -1, -1, -1, 
    -1,  1,  1, 
    -1, -1,  1, 
     1, -1,  1, 
     1,  1,  1 
};

float norm[6][3] = { 
    0,  0, -1,
    0,  0,  1, 
   -1,  0,  0, 
    1,  0,  0, 
    0,  1,  0, 
    0, -1,  0 
};

int idx[6][4] =
{
0, 1, 2, 3, // Rear

4, 5, 6, 7, // Front

0, 3, 5, 4, // Left

7, 6, 2, 1, // Right

0, 4, 7, 1, // Top

5, 3, 2, 6, // Bottom
};

- (void) prepareOpenGL {

    [super prepareOpenGL];

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
}


- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(dx, dy, dz);
    glRotatef(ay, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(ax, 1, 0, 0);

    glColor3fv(color);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        glNormal3fv(norm[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            glVertex3fv(v[idx[i][j]]);
       }
   glEnd();
   glFlush();
}
```

[image: My "Rectangle"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set up the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix so half of your model is clipped away. What you see is not a pyramid, but a corner of your cube with the rest of it being beneath the far plane and clipped away.

Also consider making your life easier by positioning the camera through `GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt`, so your drawing code would look like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(...);
glLoadMatrix(projectionMatrix);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(...);
glLoadMatrix(viewMatrix);

... // model transformation, vertices etc.
```

When you got this working, the next task would be to rewrite it using the programmable pipeline, b/c nobody writes software with legacy OpenGL like this.

Comment: Yep :) much better. BUT!  I added:
    
    `glLoadMatrixf( GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(45,1,1.0f,1000.0f).m);` but I still have a problem.  [image](https://pp.vk.me/c633831/v633831763/291c8/CzZrNkqvZac.jpg) . Do I need : `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);` ?

Comment: You don't have GLUT on iOS, so that's not available. What you're missing is probably glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

Comment: No effect with glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST). I talk about OSX not, iOS :)

Comment: Then in order to be able to use depth testing, you have to have a depth buffer attached to your framebuffer object. Depending on whether you use `NSOpenGLView` or `CAOpenGLLayer`, you should use the `pixelFormat` and `copyCGLPixelFormatForDisplayMask:` APIs to specify the depth buffer's accuracy.